# insert array values in a separate row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

Here, I'm inserting the dynamic array values into database table. it inserting the datas into database table perfectly. But, I need a little bit modification with this code.. it inserting the datas with `,`. But, I want to store the array values in a separate row.

NOW I GOT

```
  id  field_name

   1   aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd
```

BUT I NEED

```
   id  field_name

   1   aaa
   2   bbb
   3   ccc
   4   ddd
```

How can I achieve that?

```
$choose_general_rules = $_POST['choose_general_rules'];
        $choose_no_of_questions = $_POST['choose_no_of_questions'];
        $choose_mark_questions = $_POST['choose_mark_questions'];

        $choose_question_name = $_POST['choose_question_name'];
        $question = array();
        foreach($choose_question_name as $value) {
         $question[] = $value;
        }
        $result_question = implode(',', $question);

        $answer_1 = $_POST['answer_1'];
        $answer_one = array();
        foreach($answer_1 as $value) {
         $answer_one[] = $value;
        }
        $result_answer_one = implode(',', $answer_one);

        $answer_2 = $_POST['answer_2'];
        $answer_two = array();
        foreach($answer_2 as $value) {
         $answer_two[] = $value;
        }
        $result_answer_two = implode(',', $answer_two);

        $answer_3 = $_POST['answer_3'];
        $answer_three = array();
        foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
         $answer_three[] = $value;
        }
        $result_answer_three = implode(',', $answer_three);

        $answer_4 = $_POST['answer_4'];
        $answer_three = array();
        foreach($answer_3 as $value) {
         $answer_three[] = $value;
        }
        $result_answer_three = implode(',', $answer_three);

        try
        {
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO choose_the_correct_answer ( reference_id, general_rules, no_of_questions, mark_each_questions, question, answer_option_one, answer_option_two, answer_option_three, answer_option_four ) VALUES ( :ref_id, :choose_general_rules, :choose_no_of_questions, :choose_mark_questions, :choose_question_name, :answer_1, :answer_2, :answer_3, :answer_4 )");
            $stmt->bindParam(':ref_id', $lastid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':choose_general_rules', $choose_general_rules, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':choose_no_of_questions', $choose_no_of_questions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':choose_mark_questions', $choose_mark_questions, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':choose_question_name', $result_question, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':answer_1', $result_answer_one, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':answer_2', $result_answer_two, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':answer_3', $result_answer_three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':answer_4', $result_answer_three, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error Inserting datas into database :" .$e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change everything in this code:

```
implode(',', $question);
```

into

```
implode("\n", $question);
```

Of course the same

```
 implode(',', $answer_one);
```

into

```
 implode("\n", $answer_one);
```

and so on

Comment: no. it doesn't work. it inserting the datas like this  `aaa\nbbb\nccc\n`. I want to store these values in a separate row...

Comment: Have you used "\n" or '\n' ? You need to use "\n" to interpret it is a new line character.

Comment: it goes to the next line in a same td. but, this is not i'm expected. `INSERT IN A SEPARATE ROW WITH SPECIFIC AUTO ID`

Comment: So you should create specific tables and insert data in loop for them instead of inserting data to one common table